# Expanding a numpy array of matrices with zeros

Tags: python, numpy

What's the most efficient way to pad an array of matrices with zeros?

example:

```
# Lets construct an array of 2 matrices from 3 arrays of vectors
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])       # 2 vectors
B = np.array([[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])     # 2 vectors
C = np.array([[12,13,14],[15,16,17]]) # 2 vectors
M = np.dstack((A,B,C))
'''
# Result: array([[[ 0,  6, 12],
                  [ 1,  7, 13],
                  [ 2,  8, 14]],

                 [[ 3,  9, 15],
                  [ 4, 10, 16],
                  [ 5, 11, 17]]]) #
'''
```

I want to add a column and/or a row of zeros to every matrix element in the array such as:

```
'''
# Result: array([[[ 0,  6, 12, 0],
              [ 1,  7, 13, 0],
              [ 2,  8, 14, 0],
              [ 0,  0,  0, 0]],

             [[ 3,  9, 15, 0],
              [ 4, 10, 16, 0],
              [ 5, 11, 17, 0]
              [ 0,  0,  0, 0]]]) #
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.pad` will work, but for this case it is overkill.  We can do it directly with:

A sample 3d array (different dimensions make changes more obvious)

```
In [408]: M=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape((2,3,4))    
In [409]: M
Out[409]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

A blank array of the desired target shape

```
In [410]: M1=np.zeros((2,4,5),M.dtype)
```

Copy values from `M` to the target in the right slice range.

```
In [411]: M1[:,:-1,:-1]=M
In [412]: M1
Out[412]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  0],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15,  0],
        [16, 17, 18, 19,  0],
        [20, 21, 22, 23,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

A copy like this is required.  There's no way of expanding the size of `M` itself.  `pad` returns a new array as well, having performed a general version of this allocate and copy.  So there isn't much of an efficiency issue.

You could also concatenate (or 'append') a 0 row or column in the right dimensions.  But what I've illustrated does it in one step.

Comment: nice, this is about 3x faster than `np.pad` on my use case (over 1 million matrices)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to do this. You can use the second input argument to specify the amount to pad before and after the data in each of the dimensions of the array. Then specify a constant padding type where the padding value is 0 (the default).

```
result = numpy.pad(M, ((0,0),(0,1),(0,1)), 'constant', constant_values=0)
array([[[ 0,  6, 12,  0],
        [ 1,  7, 13,  0],
        [ 2,  8, 14,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 3,  9, 15,  0],
        [ 4, 10, 16,  0],
        [ 5, 11, 17,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```