# Extending a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have to do the following operation quite often now, so I was looking for a code that may be shorter/cleaner and/or more efficient on doing the same thing.

Say I have an `a`x`b` matrix ("`basic`"), and I want to extend it to a matrix of shape `c`x`d`, where `c > a` and `d > b`.

I see myself repeating the following code

```
extended = np.ones(extendedShape)
extended[:extendedShape[0], :extendedShape[1]] = basic
```

and then, depending on how I want the extension to work

```
extended[extendedShape[0]:, extendedShape[1]:] = basic[-1, -1]
```

or

```
extended[extendedShape[0]:, extendedShape[1]:] = basic.max()
```

And a third option is (pseudo-code)

```
for row in range(basic.shape[0]):
    extended[row, -1] = basic[row, -1]
for column range(basic.shape[1]):
    extended[-1, column] = basic[-1, column]
```

These kind of operations become very tedious. Is there a cleaner code to do this comparison?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19349410/1461210

Comment: There's a difference between code that is tedious the write, and code that is slow.  The solution to the first problem is to hide the details in a utility function. I expect `pad` will be slower than your code due to its extra generality.

Comment: On the relative speed of pad: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35714744/901925